# Displaying only categories where values are above certain level

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have an output where the amount is filtered descending from highest.

I just want to know if there's way to display rows with values of 100K and above, excluding the data that is lower than 100K.

My example data:

```
Name     |  Amount
Person 1 | 500,000
Person 2 | 400,000
Person 3 | 350,000
Person 4 | 200,000
Person 5 | 150,000
Person 6 | 90,000
Person 7 | 80,000
...
```

Desired output:

```
Name     |  Amount
Person 1 | 500,000
Person 2 | 400,000
Person 3 | 350,000
Person 4 | 200,000
Person 5 | 150,000
```

I don't know how to code or add a condition for this.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Power Query to get the result?

Go to DATA- From Table/Data- Filter- Close and load:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you describe can be achieved by turning on Autofilter or turning the data into an Excel Table object, and selecting the respective filter setting, then sort the data. If there is more data added to the list, then the filter and sort must be repeated.

If you want the filter and sort to be applied automatically, you can use Power Query to load the data, perform the filter and sort in Power Query and load the result into a different sheet. If there is more data added to the original list, you can then simply refresh the Power Query. This requires no VBA and the workbook does not need to be macro-enabled.

Power Query is available as a free add-in for Excel 2010 and 2013 and is built into the Data ribbon of later versions as "Get and Transform".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()

    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xAddress As String
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCRg As Range
    Dim xSRg As Range
    On Error Resume Next

    xAddress = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address

    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Select Range To Filter:", "Filter Range", xAddress, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set xCRg = Application.InputBox("Select Criteria range:", "Filter Range", "", , , , , 8)
    If xCRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set xSRg = Application.InputBox("Select Output Range:", "Filter Range", "", , , , , 8)

    If xSRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xRg.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, xCRg, xSRg, False
    xSRg.Worksheet.Activate
    xSRg.Worksheet.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- **Copy** & **Paste** this code as Standard 
  Module.
- Write Criteria (to filter data) in a Cell (as Shown in Screen Shot).

**Note:**

While selecting **Criteria** select Both, Column Header (in Screen Shot is **Data**) and the Cell below (**>100000**).

- **RUN** the Macro.
- Respond **Input Box** and finish with **Ok**.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple approach, in addition to the ones already mentioned, is to use a quick formula in a helper column. This does not require any code or installing any additional plugins. Put the following formula in Cell C2 to isolate the values over 100k, then double click the handle at the bottom right corner of the cell to autofill the rest of the column.

```
=IF(B2>100000,"Yes","No")
```

You can then use Excel's Filter and uncheck "No" in column C, leaving you with just the data you want!

[image]